# Switching + and - on phone charger, will it harm my phone?

Tags: charger

I'm working on a small project and I wanna know what will happen if I plug my phone into a charger with a cable that I cut and soldered again, but soldered the + wire to - and the - to +?
will it charge? will it harm my phone / battery?
Thanks

Comment: There is a small chance that the phone is fitted with reverse voltage protection to avoid such accidents. But if it isn't. then you will destroy your phone. Do you feel lucky? ...

Comment: ... well, do ya? punk?

Comment: This is obviously not a good idea, but the question is off topic because there is no basis for knowing how a given finished consumer product - *especially one that hasn't even been identified* will respond.  But naming the phone won't make it on-topic either.

Comment: It's generally not worth splicing USB cables - hard to do a good, lasting job, and they are so cheap.  If you really want to test if you got it right (and yes, it is very hard to apply meter probes to a USB connector without shorting it) test on something cheaper that *does not contain a battery pack*.

Comment: Someone upvoted this question?!? Come on! It must be joke vote! Even on the cheapest battery there is written "do not reverse polarity"!!! This is the ABC of the electronic device *user*. The question doesn't show any research effort and it's usefulness as it stands is highly debatable. I must admit it is crystal clear, though! The next sillier question would be: "if I eat a battery, would it do harm to me?"

Comment: @LorenzoDonati Well honestly, it is a good question... to help those who don't have common sense ;P

Comment: @BrianDrummond Actually, It would be up to the charger's job to include the voltage protection. I bet that phone has a reverse diode (EMF protection) in front of the power supply.

Comment: well, if there's a chance that the phone(or the charger as Bradman175 said) has a protection, why is that stupid to ask?

Comment: @Halfon3100. My criticism was aimed especially at the upvoter, which should know better. I never said the question was stupid. It was lazy.  For someone that works "on a small project", even if you are a newbie, you should have done more research. See [help]. The question could have been formulated much better. Remember that this is not a general EE forum.

Comment: @Halfon3100 EE.SE has the goal of building a *high quality* knowledge base in Q&A form. Therefore *both* questions *and* answers are required to meet some minimal quality standard. For questions we require the person who asks to show research effort on the topic he he/she asking about. Google is your friend: a simple search for "power supply polarity reversal" shows lots of interesting and relevant material.

Answer (score 7):

Most components are sensitive to polarity. Reversing the polarity will damage them. **Do not reverse the polarity.**

Comment: Contrary to what star trek will have you believe ;)